# A problem about install the python package

Tags: python

I want to use rawpy python package. However, our docker is not allowed us to use pip, so I have to add the path of the rawpy.

Accroding to the instructions of our docker, I do these steps as follows:

1. download the source of rawpy. the link is : https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/#files
   I download the last one and unzip it. I put it in my folder /home/pylib
2. mount folder     -v /home/pylib:/data/pylib
3. Add the following two lines of code at the beginning of my code:

   `import sys; 
   sys.path.insert(1, '/data/pylib')`

   1 represents /data/pylib as having priority only lower than the directory in which my codes resides. At this point, the priorities of /data/pylib are higher than the system's own path, and import rawpy will imports rawpy in /data/pylib.

But the rawpy source code have many .cpp files, such as _rawpy.cpp, and I got an error :   `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rawpy._rawpy'

It seems rawpy can be used if there exsist _rawpy.py, but there only exsist _rawpy.cpp in the rawpy folder. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean with "our docker is not allowed us to use pip"?

Comment: You have downloaded the sources, not actually installed the module. Installing it from source requires the target to have a C compiler etc. You might want to try to install a binary wheel instead, if available for your platform. [The project's PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/rawpy/) has detailed instructions in the *Installation* subsection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rawpy is a Python module with a binary component which needs to be compiled; just downloading the source and plonking it in `sys.path` won't help (as you've noticed).

Are you absolutely sure you can't use `pip`, even with the `--user` flag (so it doesn't require root privileges)?

If that is indeed the case, then you could try to download the suitable `manylinux` wheel instead, rename the `.whl` to `.zip` and use that instead as you've done with `/data/pylib` etc. The wheel will have the compiled binary extension too.